# Unable to fetch data from a common intent

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I am calling the activity RegistrationCredentialsActivity from two different activities: RegistrationActivity and ForgotPasswordActivity. I am passing activity name as StringExtra from these activities along with other details. But inside the RegistrationCredentialsActivity, I'm unable to fetch the data sent from ForgotPasswordActivity. Only activity name is fetched successfully.

I'm setting the received data as the text of a TextView of RegistrationCredentialsActivity . Anyone have any idea why this is happening?

P.S:  It is working fine for RegistrationActivity, problem is arising only for ForgotPasswordActivity

**RegistrationCredentialsActivity**(where I'm setting received data to a TextView):

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration_credentials)
        text = findViewById(R.id.txtRegDetails)
        var string = ""
        if(intent != null){
            val activity = intent.getStringExtra("activity")
            println("Activity = "+activity.toString())          //this line is printed as expected
            if(activity.contentEquals("RegistrationActivity")) {
                string += "Name: " + intent.getStringExtra("name") + "\n"
                string += "Email: " + intent.getStringExtra("email") + "\n"
                string += "Mobile no.: " + intent.getStringExtra("mobile") + "\n"
                string += "Address: " + intent.getStringExtra("address")
            }
            else if(activity.contentEquals("ForgotPassword")){
                println("Inside else block123")       //this line is also printed
                string += "Email: "+intent.getStringExtra("email")+"\n"   //problem lies in these
                string += "Mobile: "+intent.getStringExtra("mobile")          //two lines
            }
        }
        text.text = string
    }
```

**RegistrationActivity:**

```
val intent = Intent(this@RegistrationActivity,RegistrationCredentialsActivity::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("name",name)
                intent.putExtra("email",email)
                intent.putExtra("mobile",mobile)
                intent.putExtra("address",address)
                intent.putExtra("activity","RegistrationActivity")
                startActivity(intent)
```

**ForgotPasswordActivity:**

```
val intent = Intent(this@ForgotPasswordActivity,RegistrationCredentialsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("activity","ForgotPassword")
            intent.putExtra("email",email)
            intent.putExtra("mobile",mobile)
            startActivity(intent)
```

When called from RegistrationActivity(correct):

[image]

When called from ForgotPasswordActivity(incorrect):

[image]

Comment: seems email, mobile is blank while sending.

Comment: mobile and email fields might be empty.

Answer (score 1):

it seem that "email" and "mobile" variables passed in the forgot password intent are empty

test this:

```
val intent = Intent(this@ForgotPasswordActivity,RegistrationCredentialsActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("activity","ForgotPassword")
            intent.putExtra("email","TEST")
            intent.putExtra("mobile","TEST")
            startActivity(intent)
```

you will probably find that in this case TEST will be written..

Then check if you set "email" and  "mobile" variables correctly and that they are not empty.